# How can I fix video player overflow in landscape mode?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-sliver, flutter-video-player, flutter-expanded

When I changed the phone orientation to landscape video player gives bottom overflow, I'm trying several ways to deal with this. I can't use two listViews because I need the video player to stay at the top and only the list can be scrolled. Can someone help me?

```
Container(
        color: context.theme.color.primary,
        child: SafeArea(
          bottom: false,
          left: false,
          right: false,
          child: Scaffold(
            body: OrientationBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, Orientation orientation) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    MyVideoPlayer(
                      orientation: orientation,
                      videoDetails: viewModel.videoDetails,
                      languageCode: context.currentLanguage,
                    ),
                    ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: [
                        VideoInfoExpansionTile(
                          title: viewModel.videoDetails.title,
                          author: viewModel.videoDetails.author ?? '',
                          publicationDate: viewModel.videoDetails.publicationDate,
                          description: viewModel.videoDetails.description,
                        ),
                        if (viewModel.videoSeriesPlaylist.items.isNotEmpty) ...{
                          VidePlayListHeader(
                            title: viewModel.videoSeriesPlaylist.title ?? '',
                          ),
                          VideoPlaylist(
                            videoSeriesPlaylist: viewModel.videoSeriesPlaylist,
                          ),
                        }
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```